# when multiple React DOM components are used without outer div then JSX won't compile

Tags: reactjs

Consider this example which won't compile:

```js
/** @jsx React.DOM */

var Hello = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return <div>Hello</div>;
  }
});

var World = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return <div>World</div>;
  }
});

var Main = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
        <Hello />
        <World /> 
    );
  }
});

React.renderComponent(<Main />, document.body);
```

But any of these  combinations does work:

```html
<div>
 <Hello />
 <World />
</div>

 <Hello />
 //<World />

 //<Hello />
 <World />
```

Wanted to know if multiple components should always be surrounded by div tags.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the render function should return only one component.

From the docs: http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html

> The render() method is required.
>
> When called, it should examine this.props and this.state and return a single child component

Comment: Yep, this is correct. As you pointed out, you can almost always just wrap the result in a `<div>` tag. (Sometime in the future we'd like to get rid of this restriction.)

Comment: its 2016 and that time in future hasn't come yet

Comment: It's 2019 and that time hasn't come yet.

Answer (score 4):

There's a simple way to get around this limitation:

```
var Hello = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return <div>Hello</div>;
  }
});

var World = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return <div>World</div>;
  }
});

var HelloWorld = [Hello, World];

var Main = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
        {HelloWorld}
    );
  }
});

React.renderComponent(<Main />, document.body);
```

Comment: I got `A valid ReactComponent must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object.`

Comment: This used to work in earlier versions of React. Apparently you won't be able to get around this limitation with the newest versions. :(

Answer (score 1):

> React components can only render a single root node. If you want to
>   return multiple nodes they must be wrapped in a single root.

As specified on the Official React Site: [React Docs](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/displaying-data.html#components-are-just-like-functions)