# Do I have to wrap components in html tags?

Tags: reactjs

I've seen the pattern that components always seem to be wrapped in HTML tags.

I've searched [the docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/getting-started.html) to check if this is mandatory, but not found anything on the topic.

If the above isn't true, why do I get an error on the first code example and not on the second?

```
const App = (props) => {
  return (
    <Header />
    {props.children}
  );
};

const App = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Header />
      {props.children}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: maybe interesting? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22280315/when-multiple-react-dom-components-are-used-without-outer-div-then-jsx-wont-com. This seems to say that one component must be in one DOM node subtree? I don't think I have explained that well ;-/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, it's not required to wrap your render in a `div` or other html element specifically, you can render using a Component as the root element. You cannot however have more than one root element, that is why you are getting an error in the first example.  The following would work however:

```
render() {
   <Header>
     <h1>Hello World</h1>
     <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
   </Header>
}
```

In the end you will still likely have to have some sort of wrapper `div` within the Header component as you cannot have more than 1 root element.

I did read somewhere that the React team are looking into this, and that the new reconciler supports multiple root elements, however it is far from finished.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to wrap them specifically in HTML tags. You could wrap them in a custom component instead.

The error you're getting is because a component has to return a single node, which is why you can't do this:

```js
// WRONG
const App = (props) => {
  return (
    <Header />
    {props.children}
  );
};
```